# Своя кнопка с 3 разными полями

Tags: c#, wpf

Как создать свою кнопку с 3 разными полями?

1. Изображение
2. Текст
3. Текст с другим фоном

Пытался через Пользовательский элемент управления, но изображение не связывалось с остальным...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Положить в контент кнопки грид, в него изображение и дар тестовых блока. Какие могут быть проблемы?

Comment: Пытался, не работает все ровно

Comment: Уважаемый, вот если я вам скажу "Пытался машину починить, не вышло", вам это даст хоть капли представления того, что конкретно в машине сломано и что не получилось? Я думаю нет! Тут все точно так же, мы знаем, что вы пытались, но где ваши попытки, где конкретное объяснение того, что не удалось сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну что же вы, люди с большим рейтингом, загоняете в угол новичка? Может человек и вправду пытался, даже изображение составил и к вопросу прикрепил.

```
<Button Width="200" Height="150"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Source="/Resources/leaf.png"/>

            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="White">
                <TextBlock  Text="Текст"  
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="#FF95349E">
                <TextBlock  Text="Текст"  
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>                            
            </Border>

        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]